# Websocket slow transfer rate in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, websocket

I’m building a WebSocket based bandwidth test which runs significantly slower in Google Chrome.
In testing, Chrome reaches ~170 - 220Mbps and stays right around that area for for the duration of the test (40 seconds ).  Oddly enough, if I minimize Chrome my speeds typically increase to about 290-310Mbps which makes me think something ‘render’ related is blocking or slowing me down but this example is really simple and nothings displaying on the page.
Testing with FireFox and IE constantly give performance right at 300-330Mbps which is my line rate.
I'm using Chrome version 39.0.2171.99m on Windows 7.

Anyone have any idea on this one?
Below is my simplified code.

```js
//socket_worker.js
function initWebSocket(ip) {

        var connection = new WebSocket("ws://"+ip+":8080"); 

        connection.onerror = function (error) {
                console.log('WebSocket Error ' + error);
        };  

        connection.onopen = function( ) {
                self.postMessage('connected');
                connection.send('startSpew');
        }   

        connection.onmessage = function (e) {
                self.postMessage( e.data.length);
        };  
};

self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
        switch (e.data.cmd) {
                case 'init':
                        initWebSocket(e.data.IP);
                        break;
                default:
                        self.postMessage('Unknown command: ' + e); 
        };  
}, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        var chromeWorker = new Worker('js/socket_worker.js');
        chromeWorker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
                        
         }, false);

        chromeWorker.postMessage({'cmd':'init', 'IP': ’10.0.1.25’});
</script>
<h2>WebSocket Test</h2>
```

Server side is pretty basic.  I’m using websocketd (https://github.com/joewalnes/websocketd) to run this perl script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use IO::Handle;

 STDOUT->autoflush(1);

my $load = "pugsrule!pugsrule!pugsrule!pugsrule!pugsrule!pugsrule!pugsrule!pugsrule!pugsrule!pugsrule!pugsrule!pugsrule!pugsrule!pugsrule!pugsrule!pugsrule!pugsrule!pugsrule!"; 


my $pugload = $load.$load.$load.$load.$load;
my $len;
while (<>) {
        if($_  =~ 'startSpew'){
                while(1){
                 print $pugload."\n";
                }   
        }   
        if($_ =~ 'uppload'){
                $len = length($_);
                print "$len\n";
        }   
}
```

Comment: What does your server-side code look like?

Comment: Added server side code.

Comment: I was able to get around the slow down by opening 2 more sockets in separate threads via WebWorker.  Its sort of a band-aid approach but it's working for the time being.  I still see the speed increase drastically when minimizing the window but at least I'm where I need to be.   * Here's to a complete HTML5 bandwidth test :-D

Comment: Also filed a bug report and seems others are experiencing similar issues. 
Here's the link to that thread:  https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=456476